# JavaScript: How to skip over current item in array during a for loop? (continue?)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, continue

EDIT: I don't want to skip index 1. I want to skip the current (clicked on) element. Also, see below for more of the code as requested. You'll see that I have a class `CatListItem` and five instances of that class in an array `allCatListItems`.

Here's some context for the question: I have a list of cats. When I click on a cat's name (list item), I want that cat's picture and other info to be appended to the page (got that down). When a cat is clicked, I also want any other cat that is being displayed to be hidden (that way there is only one cat on the screen at a time).

I'm trying to accomplish this with a `for` loop, but obviously if it iterates over every item in the array, then when I click an item, the cat being clicked will be hidden as well.

I want to skip the current item in the array and only run the code on the other items. Using continue, I know I can skip a specific item (item [1](https://jsfiddle.net/2r7asf3e/) in the below example). This will run my code on every item in the array except that at index one. But how can I make that `continue` dynamic? Meaning... how can I hide all of the cats, except the one being currently clicked?

Here's the loop that skips index 1:

```
CatListItem.prototype.hideCats = function() {
    allCatListItems.forEach(function(cat) {
        cat.a.addEventListener('click', function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < allCatListItems.length; i++) {
                if (i === 1) {
                    continue;
                }
                allCatListItems[i].img.className = 'hide';
            };
        });
    });
}

var allCatListItems = [
    catListItem1 = new CatListItem('El', 'images/el.jpg', 'el'),
    catListItem2 = new CatListItem('Widdle Baby', 'images/widdle-baby.jpg',     'widdle-baby'),
    catListItem3 = new CatListItem('Mama', 'images/mama.jpg', 'mama'),
    catListItem4 = new CatListItem('Legion', 'images/legion.jpg', 'legion'),
    catListItem5 = new CatListItem('Boy', 'images/boy.jpg', 'boy'),
];
```

EDIT: Here's a fiddle.[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2r7asf3e/) Click the names to see the functionality without the hideCats function. Then uncomment where it says to to see my issue.

I'm starting to think maybe a for loop isn't the best option?

Comment: Can you show your click event handler as well

Comment: get the item clicked index on click then if(i === index) continue;

Comment: You need to identify and skip over the desired element. How to do it will depend on your actual code, which you didn't provide, but will likely be a comparison between `this` and the current element in the list.

Comment: How are you creating the variable `allCatListItems`.   You can make sure you don't add the clicked element into this  variable at aall and normal for loop will work fine...

Comment: @DaniloSilva how to do that? Perhaps provide it in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case compare the event.target(its the element clicked)

EDIT: allCatListItems[i] needs it's `.a` property attached to it in the if statement (this is what contains the anchor element). This is because the event listener is grabbing an anchor tag, so `e.target` will be returning an anchor tag as well. The if statement will never return as true if you aren't comparing the same type of element.

```
cat.a.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < allCatListItems.length; i++) {
       if (allCatListItems[i].a === e.target) {
           continue;
       }
       allCatListItems[i].img.className += ' hide';
    }
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle, it doesn't use the same element names, but it should be doing what you want. https://jsfiddle.net/5qb4rwzc/

Comment: `else` wouldn't be necessary. The original code works. They're asking how to target the specific cat.

Comment: I would recommend setting `display: none` on the cats not being clicked and setting `display: block` on the cat being clicked.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not actually trying to skip over index 1. I have THAT working, but I want to skip over the current element being clicked. Also, I do use display:none to hide them, thank you! :)

Comment: you just need to compare what is being clicked to what you want to change.

Comment: I understand the logic, but what does e.target actually return to me? I tried it and that code doesn't work.

Comment: Just saw the fiddle. The idea is the same, but I don't want to hide the list elements. When I click one, it shows makes a picture (and other info) appear. When I click another list item, I want the other one to be hidden and the clicked one to appear.

Comment: e.target is the clicked element. is just short for event.

Comment: Marked as correct. The only thing missing is `allCatListItems[i]` in the if statement needs the `.a` after to it to be correctly compared to `e.target`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').on('click', function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
  var items = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if(i === index) continue;
    items[i].style = "display:none;";
  }
});
```

Comment: I think I get what you are trying to do. Can you share in vanilla js and not jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Its really depend on how you call the function "hideCat".  Realizing that each time that function is called, more eventListeners are add to every cat item.  Each time a cat is clicked, more than one event fired.  Perhaps you should re-structure how to attach eventListeners to each cat item.